# Как правильно написать CssSelector, используя c# и OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, telegram, css-selectors, chromedriver

Ознакамливаюсь с автоматизацией пользовательского интерфейса.
Для начала решила написать простенький код на C#, используя OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome, который вбивал бы в поиск Telegram ссылку на чат, выбирал его и отправлял сообщение.
Определить текстовое поле для поиска и ввести в него текст я смогла, а вот с оставшимися двумя шагами возникли проблемы.

Код на C#:

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://web.telegram.org/#/login");

IWebElement query = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[type='search']"));
query.SendKeys("https://t.me/bAHdiTu");

IWebElement query1 = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("ul.nav.nav-pills.nav-stacked li:first-child"));
query1.Click();

IWebElement query2 = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div[class='composer_rich_textarea']"));
query2.SendKeys("тест");
```

Для выбора чата нужно выбрать первый элемент из ul - li:first-child. Я попробовала выбрать его по классам, но вылетает исключение: "OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: "no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"ul.nav.nav-pills.nav-stacked li:first-child"}". Поле для ввода тоже пробовала выбрать по классам, но не получилось.

HTML-разметка в Telegram WEB:
[image: HTML-разметка в Telegram WEB]

[image: Выделение этого чата]

[image: HTML-разметка в Telegram WEB]

[image: Выделение поля для ввода]

Помогите пожалуйста правильно описать селектор.

Comment: Пока толко `CssSelector("div[class='composer_rich_textarea']")` бросилось в глаза, надо бы так `CssSelector("div.composer_rich_textarea")`

Comment: посмотрите вот [это](https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/css-selectors-tutorial-for-selenium-with-examples), обратите внимание на `:first-of-type`

Comment: Спасибо посмотрю. Примеры смотрела здесь - https://devqa.io/selenium-css-selectors/

Comment: @aepot я взяла пример с этого сайта и сделала ```CssSelector(".im_dialog_wrap:first-of-type")``` и ```CssSelector("div.composer_rich_textarea")``` всё равно ошибка

Comment: Ну пока одна мысль, что сайт может подгружаться через AJAX, и событие готовности страницы приходит Селениуму раньше, чем по факту страница загрузится. Следовательно на момент выполнения `FindElement` нужных элементов еще может не быть. Попробуйте либо добавить для проверки паузу после навигации, либо какой-нибудь другой сайт открыть, будет ли там работать. И [вот](https://habr.com/ru/post/180047/), обратите внимание в классе на 2 функции `WaitReadyState()` и `WaitAjax()`. Возможно механизм одной из них поможет вам разобраться с задержками при загрузках страницы.

Comment: [Вот](https://www.selenium.dev/docs/site/en/webdriver/waits/) еще всякие ожидалки

Comment: @aepot спасибо, завтра попробую добавить ожидание и отпишу, но всё равно мне кажется что тут с самим селектором проблема. Мне на других форумах посоветовали сделать не через CssSelector, а с помощью by.xpath, я сделала и всё равно ошибки(

Comment: Проверить селектор просто, откройте консоль браузера и там напишите `document.querySelectorAll('ваш.селектор')`.

Comment: @aepot а я не додумалась на js потестить, так ведь быстрее, спасибо. Я взяла нужный селектор на js - `document.querySelector("body > div.page_wrap > div.im_page_wrap.clearfix.im_page_peer_not_selected > div > div.im_dialogs_col_wrap.noselect.im_dialogs_col_search > div.im_dialogs_col > div > div.im_dialogs_scrollable_wrap.nano-content > ul > li:nth-child(1)")` Вот в таком он виде и в консоли всё сработало, но как его отформатировать, чтобы на C# корректно работал?

Comment: Это уже другой вопрос, не относящийся к изначальному, можно его задать отдельно.